# C++ Print string to debug console gives out error

Tags: c++

I've been trying to print to the debug console and the code that I've found for printing string doesn't work. The following lines are what I have been using to print to the debug. But I received the following error on the `OutputDebugString(newPos.c_str());`

```
line: argument of type "const char *" is incompatible with parameter of type "LPCWSTR".
```

I've also placed below the position and player position structs that I've used in the code and that are created earlier in the code.

```cpp
struct Position {
    int x;
    int y;
    string currentObj;
};

struct PlayerPosition {
    int x;
    int y;
};

string newPos = gameMap[playerPos.x + 1][playerPos.y].currentObj;
OutputDebugString(newPos.c_str());
```

I've tried to go through some previous StackOverflow questions like this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1333527/how-do-i-print-to-the-debug-output-window-in-a-win32-app) and this other StackOverflow form [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46822999/c-argument-of-type-is-incompatible-with-parameter-of-type), but they haven't helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like [`OutputDebugStringW` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/debugapi/nf-debugapi-outputdebugstringw) is selected as `OutputDebugString` in your environment.

A simple fix is using [`OutputDebugStringA` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/debugapi/nf-debugapi-outputdebugstringa) explicitly instead of `OutputDebugString`:

```cpp
OutputDebugStringA(newPos.c_str());
```

Comment: Thanks, that seemed to fix the problem. Though if possible, I would like to ask another question; when I run the code and check the output from debug section, the only text that appears is that the c++ code was loaded correctly. Meanwhile, the code around the debug is still working, but I'm not receiving any debug messages. I assume this is an environment problem similar to the different OutputDebugString.

Comment: @MontainProduction  Messages from `OutputDebugString` only appear in the Debug Console not the terminal or standard output.  So the program needs to be run with a debugger attached and the Debug Console visible in the debugger.  If nothing is visible try a hardcoded literal string as a test.